# Populate a numeric column with random values

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

This is my table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTnwX.png)

I did this to populate it:

```
update AEROPORTO.RESERVA 
   set VALOR = random()*(5000-1500)+1500
where cod_reserva is not null
```

but `random()` has double precision and i what my values like this:

- 111,11
- 222,22

and `round()` doesn't use double precision.

I've tried to change the data type of the field Valor but didn't worked. Tried numeric, monetary and float.

I need to run a script that populates randomly this field with only 2 digits precision.

Comment: Don't use floating points to represent decimals, instead multiply your value by `100` to store an integer value and by `0.01` when reading.

Comment: If you only want two decimals, define your column with 2 decimals e.g.: `numeric(12,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `round` functions, `round(dp or numeric)` returns integer, and `round(v numeric, s int)` that returns `numeric`. Try the following:

```
update AEROPORTO.RESERVA 
   set VALOR = round((random()*(5000-1500)+1500)::numeric, 2)
where cod_reserva is not null
```